# How can I change the colour of my question after submission?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

In my code, I have many questions. After submission, I would like to change the colour of the question to green if it was correct, or red if it was wrong.

```js
     
document.getElementById("submit-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
    var totalQuestions = questions.length;
    var correctAnswers = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      var question = questions[i];
      var selectedOption = question.querySelector("input:checked");

      if (selectedOption) {
        var answer = selectedOption.value;
        var correctAnswer = question.getAttribute("data-correct-answer");
        if (answer === correctAnswer) {
          correctAnswers++;
        }
      }
    }

    var resultMessage = "You answered " + correctAnswers + " out of " + totalQuestions + " questions correctly.";
    alert(resultMessage);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" data-correct-answer="c">
      <p>Question 1:</p>
      <p>What is the value of 2 + 2?</p>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"> a) 2</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"> b) 3</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c"> c) 4</label>
    </div>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

I have tried using ChatGPT (which was pretty useless) and the internet. ChatGPT didn't understand the question and there was nothing on the internet to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply the style change with a dynamic class like `.correct` and `.incorrect` for answers that are correct or incorrect.

The style definitions might look like:

```
<style>
  .correct {
    color: green;
  }

  .incorrect {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

and then in your script:

```
(...)

if (selectedOption) {
        var answer = selectedOption.value;
        var correctAnswer = question.getAttribute("data-correct-answer");

        if (answer === correctAnswer) {
          correctAnswers++;
          /* add class here, if correct */
          question.classList.add("correct");
        } else {
          /* add class here, if incorrect */
          question.classList.add("incorrect");
        }
      }
    }

(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("submit-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
  var totalQuestions = questions.length;
  var correctAnswers = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var question = questions[i];
    var selectedOption = question.querySelector("input:checked");

    if (selectedOption) {
      var answer = selectedOption.value;
      var correctAnswer = question.getAttribute("data-correct-answer");
      
      if (answer === correctAnswer) {
        correctAnswers++;
        question.classList.add("correct");
        question.classList.remove("wrong");
      } else {
        question.classList.add("wrong");
        question.classList.remove("correct");
      }
    }
  }

  var resultMessage = "You answered " + correctAnswers + " out of " + totalQuestions + " questions correctly.";
  alert(resultMessage);
});
```

```css
.question.correct {
  color: green;
}

.question.wrong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question" data-correct-answer="c">
  <p>Question 1:</p>
  <p>What is the value of 2 + 2?</p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="a"> a) 2</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="b"> b) 3</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="c"> c) 4</label>
</div>

<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

By question, I'm guessing you mean the entire DIV. If that is the case, then give the DIV an ID and a NAME.

```
<div class="question" data-correct-answer="c" id="question" name="question">
```

Then, you'll be able to set the color via the ID or the Name. It's more common to use ID, but at some point it became convention to add both the ID and the Name attribute. Using "document.getElementById()" will parse through the document for whatever you place into the parentheses, in this answer I've given it the ID of "question." You then access the CSS attribute via ".style" and the color attribute via ".color." You then reference that based on the condition then got the right answer or wrong...

```
if (answer === correctAnswer) {
  correctAnswers++;
  document.getElementById("question").style.color = "green";
} else {
  document.getElementById("question").style.color = "red";
}
```

From there, pick whichever shade/hue you like and enjoy!